# (Re) Weighting Random CSV samples in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, random, pandas

I have a (large) directory CSV with columns [0:3] = Phone Number, Name, City, State.

I created a random sample of 20,000 entries, but it was, of course, weighted drastically to more populated states and cities.

How would I write a python code (using CSV or Pandas - please no linecache) that would equally prioritize/weight each unique city and each state (individually, not as a pair), and also limit each unique city to 3 picks?

---

TRICKIER idea: How would I write a python code such that for each random line that gets picked, it checks whether that city has been picked before.  If that city has been picked before, it ignores it and picks a random line again, reducing the number of considered previous picks for that city by one.  So, say that it randomly picks San Antonio, which has been picked twice before.  The script ignores this pick, places it back into the list, reduces the number of currently considered previous San Antonio picks, then randomly chooses a line again.  IF it picks a line from San Antonio again, then it repeats the previous process, now reducing considered San Antonio picks to 0.  So it would have to pick San Antonio three times in a row to add another line from San Antonio.  For future picks, it would have to pick San Antonio four times in a row, plus one for each additional pick.

I don't know how well the second option would work to "scatter" my random picks - it's just an idea, and it looks like a fun way to learn more pythonese.  Any other ideas along the same line of thought would be greatly appreciated.  Insights into statistical sampling and sample scattering would also be welcome.

Comment: I see a big problem with this code. If you have, say 20 cities in your data, the chance of picking the same city twice in a row, is roughly 1/20. This means that you would only get 1 sample from 20 queries when all cities have been picked one time. When all cities have been picked twice, you would only get 1 sample for every 400 picks. (this grows exponentially as `(1/20)^n`)

Comment: Is the data sorted in any way?

Comment: It's easy enough to throw into a CSV editor and sort it by any column, I'm sure.  As it stands, I believe it's sorted by state.  Also, regarding your worry, I believe you're right - it was an idea I was tossing out.  I would love to hear better ideas and see their method of implementation - I'm as much looking to learn about statistical weighting methods as I am about scripting them!

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding exactly what you're trying to do.

I think what you're wanting is a bit more complex. I don't quite understand your question, but hopefully this example gives you some food for thought.

However, you probably want to make use of various libraries for your sampling. All in all, you can do this in just a few lines with `pandas`:

```
# Group by city, state
groups = df.groupby(['state', 'city'])

# Then get a result with n from each unique city,state
def choose_n(x, n):
    idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(x)), n, replace=True)
    return x.take(idx)

num_from_each = 2
sample = groups.apply(choose_n, num_from_each)
```

As a more complete example, with some randomly generated data using the `picka` library:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import picka

# Generate some realistic random data using "picka"
num = 200
names = [picka.name() for _ in range(num)]
phones = [picka.phone_number() for _ in range(num)]
# Let's limit it to a smaller number of cities and states...
cities = np.random.choice(['Springfield', 'Houston', 'Dallas'], num)
states = np.random.choice(['IL', 'TX', 'TN', 'CA'], num)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(name=names, phone=phones, city=cities, state=states))

# Group by city, state
groups = df.groupby(['state', 'city'])

# Then get a result with n from each unique city,state
def choose_n(x, n):
    idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(x)), n, replace=True)
    return x.take(idx)

num_from_each = 2
sample = groups.apply(choose_n, num_from_each)
print sample
```

This results in:

```
                              city      name         phone state
state city
CA    Dallas      72        Dallas    Sarina  133-258-6775    CA
                  46        Dallas     Dusty  799-563-7043    CA
      Houston     158      Houston     Artie  591-835-3043    CA
                  195      Houston  Federico  899-315-1205    CA
      Springfield 66   Springfield     Ollie  326-076-1329    CA
                  53   Springfield        Li  702-555-6594    CA
IL    Dallas      154       Dallas       Lou  146-404-9668    IL
                  39        Dallas     Ollie  399-256-7836    IL
      Houston     190      Houston  Scarlett  278-499-6901    IL
                  89       Houston    Rhonda  619-966-3691    IL
      Springfield 119  Springfield       Jae  180-444-0253    IL
                  130  Springfield     Tawna  630-953-5200    IL
TN    Dallas      25        Dallas     Frank  475-964-0279    TN
                  50        Dallas     Kiara  764-240-4802    TN
      Houston     95       Houston   Britney  661-490-5178    TN
                  107      Houston    Tommie  648-945-5608    TN
      Springfield 55   Springfield     Kecia  891-643-2644    TN
                  55   Springfield     Kecia  891-643-2644    TN
TX    Dallas      116       Dallas      Mara  636-589-0435    TX
                  98        Dallas   Lajuana  759-788-4742    TX
      Houston     103      Houston     Casey  600-522-2874    TX
                  140      Houston    Rachal  762-082-9017    TX
      Springfield 197  Springfield     Staci  021-981-7593    TX
                  168  Springfield  Sherrill  754-736-8409    TX
```

Comment: I'm getting a lot of repeats - how do I stop this code from giving me repeat results and also forcing 3 results from each city/state?  (3 max)

Comment: @Xodarap777 - That's what the `replace=True` in `np.random.choice` specifies.  (I mistakenly assumed that you wanted sampling with replacement.) You can just specify `replace=False`, but you'll get an error with city/states that have less than 3 listings.  If you'd like to only repeat when there's less than three, then specify `replace=len(x) < n`.  If you want to just return all of the available listings when there are fewer than 3, then you can just add an extra line (`if len(x) <= n: return x`).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your trickier idea is the one you're actually looking for, here's an implementation that would take care of it. It doesn't use `pandas`, which might be a mistake, but I didn't see that as a strict requirement on your question and I figured this would be more straightforward:

```
def random_city_sample(n, input_file='my_csv.csv')
    samples = set()
    city_counter = collections.Counter()
    reader = csv.reader(open(input_file), delimiter=",", quotechar="\"")

    # Shuffles your entries as well as removing duplicate entries
    sample_set = set(tuple(row) for row in reader)
    while len(samples) < n:
        added_samples = sampling_run(sample_set, city_counter)

        # Add selected samples to universal sample list
        samples.update(added_samples)

        # Remove only those samples which have been successfully selected
        sample_set = sample_set.difference(added_samples)

def sampling_run(master_set, city_counter):
    city_ticker = 0
    current_city = ''
    samples_selected = set()
    for entry in master_set:
        city = entry[2]
        if city == current_city:
            city_ticker += 1
        else:
            current_city = city
            city_ticker = 1
        if city_ticker > city_counter[city]:
            samples_selected.update(entry)
    return samples_selected
```

Though this does mean that if you have a very sparse csv, there might be issues, if you change the iteration to a random sample it gets around that, but I'm not sure if you want to or not:

```
def random_city_sample(n, input_file='my_csv.csv')
    samples = set()
    city_counter = collections.Counter()
    reader = csv.reader(open(input_file), delimiter=",", quotechar="\"")

    # Shuffles your entries as well as removing duplicate entries
    sample_set = set(tuple(row) for row in reader)

    while len(samples_selected) < n
        city_ticker = 0
        current_city = ''
        samples_selected = set()

        entry = random.sample(sample_set, 1)
        city = entry[2]
        if city == current_city:
            city_ticker += 1
        else:
            current_city = city
            city_ticker = 1
        if city_ticker > city_counter[city]:
            samples.update(entry)
            sample_set.remove(entry)
```

I hope that helps! Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I love how Pythonic this is.  I am chewing it slowly, thank you!